# Pages: line break appears before end of line

Tags: pages, bug, iwork

For some very strange reason, I cannot seem to fit the text on line 2 inside the empty space of the 1st line. I tried deleting the words and re-writing them, which didn't work.
I tried changing font sizes back and forth, still didn't work.

I couldn't find this bug being referenced anywhere...

In the animation below / screen cap, I am only using delete and text keys of the computer.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to retype the space character between "altération" and "handicapante" as well? Might be a non-breaking one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be [Non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) between the words. Please press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to enable non visible characters. Here's example:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that helps since I do see these when pressing this key combination. But how did this weird space get there? I didn't do anything special, just type! And yet my document seems scattered with these

Comment: Key combination to insert Non-breaking space is `⌥`+`Space`, maybe You did this by accident? Or this text was copied from other source?

Comment: No, like I said, I just typed the text... Weird! I'll leave the invisible characters on to watch this strange phenomenon closely... Thanks a lot for your help!